# Where does this requirement for a Promise<void> come from?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api

I have a helper function that uses `fetch` to get data from an API:

```js
const callApi = (endpoint: string, method = 'GET', body?: string): Promise<Response> => {
  // decide if url is dev or prod
  const url = getUrl()
  const headers = new Headers()
  headers.set('infinote-token', store.infinoteToken as string)
  const initObject = {
    headers: headers,
    method: method,
    body: method === 'POST' ? body : undefined
  }
  return fetch(`${url}${endpoint}`, initObject)
    .then(r => {
      if (r.ok) {
        apiIsOnline()
      } else if (r.status === 403) {
        store.needToSetToken = true
        apiIsOnline()
      } else {
        apiIsOffline()
        throw Error(r.statusText)
      }
    })
    .catch((reason) => {
      log.debug(`API call rejected because: ${reason}`)
      return Promise.reject()
    })
}
```

It generates a TS error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Promise<void | Response>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Response>'.    
          Type 'void | Response' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
            Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
```

**Where does this requirement for `Promise<void>` come from?**

My understanding is that `fetch` [returns a `Promise<Response>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch):

> The promise resolves to the Response object representing the response to your request.

Comment: It's not a requirement. It's the other way around the *requirement* is that you produce `Promise<Response>` - it's the return type specified for the function. However, the function also possibly returns `Promise<void>` which clashes with the requirement. Normally that's because not all branches produce a `Promise<Response>` however, in your case none of them do but TS is being generous and assumes the result *could* also be `Response` some times. But it's wrong - it's always `void` because in the `.then()` you don't return any respnse, only a rejection or nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, fetch returns a `Promise<Response>`. But you are handling this result with `.then(r => ...)` This `r` is the `Response` you get back from `fetch`. The overall result of a promise chain `foo().then().then()...` is the  result of the last `then()`. But your `then()` handler doesn't return anything (well technically it does return a `Promise<void>`). Thus the overall result of your `fetch(...).then(...)`  is a `Promise<void>`. If you just want to pass through the Response, add a `return r` to your `then()`

```
return fetch(`${url}${endpoint}`, initObject)
  .then(r => {
    if (r.ok) {
      apiIsOnline()
    } else if (r.status === 403) {
      store.needToSetToken = true
      apiIsOnline()
    } else {
      apiIsOffline()
      throw Error(r.statusText)
    }
    return r;
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Besides giving me the solution, it finally made me sit through promises that I was using for years without really understanding them (I am an amateur developer of personal software). I actually thought that there was something magical in how the `.then()` are chained but your clear answer opened my eyes. Thanks a lot.